# how to use 50% width and height in android linear layout

Tags: android

I want to create android kind of layout like this :

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7stu.png)

I created same this with relative layout but I can't place second container with 50% width and height.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/akhbar"
                android:id="@+id/akhbar_panel" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/amozesh_panel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/amozesh" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: my image url : 

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8333857076/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 3):

I think a better parent for this view would be `ConstraintLayout`, but if you have to use `LinearLayout` then you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#fac"
        android:text="one"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#afc"
            android:text="two"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#caf"
            android:text="three"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: and what about it if i want to place another container below the container "one" ?

Comment: im trying to create this layout : 

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8333859484/format.PNG

but i cant place my views its my only problem please help me to how place like this ... thanks bro

Comment: please look at my layout picture and help me bro thanks

Comment: @ElyasErfani Looks like you'd start with a vertical LinearLayout. For each row that has two small views next to a big view, use a horizontal LinearLayout like the one in my answer. For each row that's just one big view, you can just use a view with `match_parent` width and whatever height you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve it using ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#fac"
        android:text="one"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#afc"
        android:text="two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/one"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/three"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#caf"
        android:text="three"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/one"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```